# Using server time to create a timer in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to create a timer using the server time in meteor. On the client side, inside the `Meteor.startup` function, I make a call to the server to get the server time and keep it in a session variable. After that this server call will be made every 15 minutes using `Meteor.setInterval` function.

On server `main.js`,

```
return Meteor.methods({

    getServerTime: function () {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        return d;
    }

});
```

On Client `main.js` ,

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

   Session.set('serverTime', false);
    // get serverTime on startup
    Meteor.setServerTime();
    // update serverTime every 15min
    Meteor.setInterval(function() { Meteor.setServerTime(); }, 900000);


});

Meteor.setServerTime = function() {
  //get server time (it's in milliseconds)
  Meteor.call("getServerTime", function (error, serverTime) {

    Session.set('serverTime', serverTime);

  });
};
```

On the client side timer template code, I get the server time from session, `Session.get('serverTime');`, for use in the timer code. The problem is, if I have the timer taken on two different browsers and refresh one of them, timer is changed on that browser not affecting the timer on the other browser because of keeping the server time on session.

I am looking for a way so that whatever the user does on his/her browser the timer is not affected and it should always be same of every browser using the sever time.

Is there any other way/idea to tackle this scenario and keep the timer uniform everywhere?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What you're getting with your `Meteor.setServerTime()` is the server's time at the time of the call.

So obviously when you have 2 browsers get the server time at different times, they will get different session values.

If you want ALL the clients connected to the server to *approximately* be able to tell the server time, you need to solve the time offset from the time NOW and the time when you got the server time.

I think I didn't explain it well and it's quite unclear. So let's show it by code.

```
Meteor.call("getServerTime", function (error, serverTime) {
  Session.set('serverTime', serverTime);
  Session.set('timeObtained', Date.now()); //local time when you got the serverTime
});
```

Then, you will use that value to solve for the `serverTime` NOW.

```
function realServerTime(){
  return Session.get('serverTime') + (Date.now() - Session.get('timeObtained'));
}
```

The `Date.now() - Session.get('timeObtained')` is the **time difference of the time now and the time you got the server's time**.

Now this is subject to a few milliseconds worth (or more, depending on the connection) of error, and to lessen that, you have to use latency approximation methods, which I won't get into this post.

But if you're in a local environment, there most probably won't be a discrepancy more than 10ms.

Comment: Note that this approach is taken by the [timesync](https://atmospherejs.com/package/timesync) package. It also does latency approximation (albeit quite crudely) and uses an HTTP request rather than a method call to get the server time (this has more predictable latency, since method calls might be blocked by ongoing methods on the same connection).